# missing return value in a boolean method

Tags: java, boolean, return-value

Hello I am working on a project for school and im having a great deal of difficulty trying to figure why my program keeps telling me im missing a return statement in all of my methods,

Here is my code:

```
public class Temperature {
 private int temperature;

 //constructors
 public int Test( int temperature )
 {
    temperature = temperature;
    return temperature;
 }
 public int TempClass()
 {
    temperature = 0;
    return 0;
 }



 // get and set methods
 public int getTemp()
 {
    return temperature;
 }

 public void setTemp(int temp)
 {
    temperature = temp;
 }

 //methods to determine if the substances
 // will freeze or boil
 public static boolean isEthylFreezing(int temp)
 {
    int EthylF = -173;

    if (EthylF <= temp)
    {System.out.print("Ethyl will freeze at that temperature");}
    else 
    return false;
 }

 public boolean  isEthylBoiling(int temp)
 {
    int EthylB = 172;

    if (EthylB >= temp)
    System.out.print("Ethyl will boil at that temperature");
    else
    return false;
 }

 public boolean  isOxygenFreezing(int temp)
 {
    int OxyF = -362;

    if (OxyF <= temp)
    System.out.print("Oxygen will freeze at that temperature");
    else
    return false;
 }

 public boolean  isOxygenBoiling(int temp)
 {
    int OxyB = -306;

    if (OxyB >= temp)
    System.out.print("Oxygen will boil at that temperature");
    else
    return false;
 }

 public boolean  isWaterFreezing(int temp)
 {
    int H2OF = 32;

    if (H2OF <= temp)
    System.out.print("Water will freeze at that temperature");
    else
    return false;
 }

 public boolean  isWaterBoiling(int temp)
 {
    int H2OB = 212;

    if (H2OB >= temp)
    System.out.print("Water will boil at that temperature");
    else
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: `public int Test( int temperature )
 {
    temperature = temperature;
    return temperature;
 }` a) is not a constructor and b) doesn't assign the argument to the object's field.

Comment: Why do you think you are getting that error?

Comment: In addition to the other problems with your code, I believe your `<=` and `>=` operations are all backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the if-else statements in your `isXXXFreezing(int temp)` and `isXXXBoiling(int temp)` methods: The section below the if-statement does not contain a return statement, only the section below the else does.

The correct code for `isEthylFreezing(int temp)` would be

```
public static boolean isEthylFreezing(int temp) {
  int EthylF = -173;

  if (EthylF <= temp)
  {
    System.out.print("Ethyl will freeze at that temperature");
    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}
```

Also in the constructor of `Test` you are assigning the variable `temperature` to itself. I guess you want to assign the function parameter `temperature` to a member variable of `Test` which is also named `temperature`? If so, write `this.temperature = temperature;`.
`this` refers to the current `Test` object and will make sure that you access the member variable.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem line:

```
if (EthylF <= temp)
{System.out.print("Ethyl will freeze at that temperature");}
else 
return false;
```

The compiler thinks that `return false` belongs with the `else` branch, so if the `EthylF <= temp` branch is taken, the method ends without returning a value. Same goes for the rest of your `boolean` getters.

Properly indenting and using curly braces would help you avoid problems like that: when you see the same code formatted as follows

```
if (EthylF <= temp) { 
    System.out.print("Ethyl will freeze at that temperature");
} else { 
    return false;
}
```

you see exactly where the problem is.

Adding `return true` in the `if` branch would solve this problem.

Comment: Vice versa for the other boolean getters.

Answer (score 1):

```
int EthylF = -173;

if (EthylF <= temp)
{System.out.print("Ethyl will freeze at that temperature");}
else 
return false;
```

This method only returns (false) if `EthylF > temp`. Otherwise, you have a print, but no return statement.

**Every** possible path of execution inside a non-void method must end with a `return` statement, or with a `throw` statement.